# How can I loop list an array containing object by starting from 1 to the last instead of starting from zero Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const array=[
{
    "firstname":"akira",
    "lastname":"laine",
    "number":"090897878",
    "like":["pizza","coding","points","brownie"]
},{
    "firstname":"harry",
    "lastname":"pooter",
    "number":"070896778",
    "like":["Hogwarts","magic","Hagrid"]
},{
    "firstname":"sherlock",
    "lastname":"Holmes",
    "number":"080896975",
    "like":["Intriguing","case","Voilin"]
},{
    "firstname":"Kristian",
    "lastname":"Vos",
    "number":"080894575",
    "like":["Javascript","Gaming","Foxes"]
}
```

]

I used recursive function to perform the task but no result yet

```
    function names(array,end) {
  if(array.length>end){
    console.log(array)
    return names(array-1,end)    
  }
```

}
names(array,1)

i am stock with this for days now. I need help on this.
You when you loop through the array containing object it list out the element in the array starting from zero to the last element in the array. My problem now is that how can loop through it starting from 1 to the last element in the array instead of zero.

Comment: use a for: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i=1; i<array.length + 1; i++) { 
   console.log(array[i-1], i)   
}
```

This was able to solve the problem for me. Thanks everyone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel says:

```
    // entire list starting a '0'
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) { console.log(JSON.stringify(array[i])) }
    console.log();
    // entire list starting a '1'
    for (let i=1; i<array.length; i++) { console.log(JSON.stringify(array[i])) }
```

Or as an alternative:

```
    var newArray = [...array];
    newArray.shift();
    console.log();
    for (let i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) { console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray[i])) }
```

If you only wanted the lastname and likes of that entry:

```
    console.log();
    for (let i=1; i<array.length; i++) { 
      console.log(`${array[i].lastname} likes: ${array[i].like}`);
    }
```

Comment: i will check..thanks

Comment: It started from 1 leaving the zero index object behind...how can i loop it from 1 which is zero to the last

Comment: Which example are you referencing?

Comment: i understand your part. You when you loop through the array containing object it list out the element in the array starting from zero to the last element in the array. My problem now is that how can loop through it starting from 1 to the last element in the array instead of zero...Do you understand

Comment: No, I'm not sure I understand.  Have you checked the console.log message to see that the output matches the display you are asking for.  There are 3 lines starting with the name 'harry' and ending with 'Kristian'.  That's the last 3 entries of your initial array.